# How to reduce boilerplate with Kleisli

Tags: scalaz, kleisli

I follow the design of the book *Functional and Reactive Domain Modeling*

And for some service methods, it only delegates work to the repository layer. Is there a way to reduce this boilerplate :

```
trait FeedbackServiceImpl extends FeedbackService {
  override def saveTFE(feedback: TripFeedbackEvent) =
    Kleisli[Future, Context, Either[String, Id]] { ctx => ctx.feedbackRepo.save(feedback) }

  override def saveLFE(feedback: LibraryFeedbackEvent) =
    Kleisli[Future, Context, Either[String, Id]] { ctx => ctx.feedbackRepo.save(feedback) }

  override def findByUser(userId: Id) =
    Kleisli[Future, Context, Seq[FeedbackEvent]] { ctx => ctx.feedbackRepo.findByUser(userId) }

  override def all =
    Kleisli[Future, Context, Seq[FeedbackEvent]] { ctx => ctx.feedbackRepo.all }

  override def findByTip(tipId: Id) =
    Kleisli[Future, Context, Seq[FeedbackEvent]] { ctx => ctx.feedbackRepo.findByTip(tipId) }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a *combinator* :

`private def kleisli[M[_], A](f: FeedbackRepository => M[A]) = 
  Kleisli.kleisli(f).local[Context](_.feedbackRepo)`

Hence we gain 2 things :

- avoid declaring the type by helping the type inference mechanism
- avoid calling `ctx.feedbackRepo` by using `local`

So we can use :

```
trait Feedbacks {
  def saveTFE(feedback: TripFeedbackEvent) = kleisli(_.save(feedback)) 
  def saveLFE(feedback: LibraryFeedbackEvent) = kleisli(_.save(feedback))
  def findByUser(userId: Id) = kleisli(_.findByUser(userId))
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you just define a function that does all the boilerplate ? Something like:

```
def repo2Kleisli[T](f: Repo => Future[T]): Kleisli[Future, Context, T]
```

You could possibly even make it implicit and reduce your code to something like:

```
 override def saveTFE(feedback: TripFeedbackEvent) = (repo: Repo) => repo.save(feedback)
```